# MLE of discrete uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Assume that $X$ is a discrete random variable with uniform distribution on the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots, N\}$, where $N$ is an unknown positive integer.

1. Find the MLE $\hat{N}_k$ of $N$, assuming that $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_k$ is a random sample from $X$.
2. Show that for $m \in \{1,2, \ldots, N\}$ we have that $P(\hat{N_k}\le m)=\left(\frac mN\right)^k$
3. Calculate the probability $P(\hat{N_k}=N).$

I would appreciate any help in (any) of the questions above. These are questions from former exams, that I am solving in order to prepare myself for upcoming exams in a Probability and Statistics course. I cannot figure out the MLE in 1. so I cannot advance to 2. and 3., although the result in 2. seems to have some kind of intuitive explanation.

Comment: It should be easy to show that $\hat N_k = \max \{X_1,\ldots,X_k\}$. Assuming that $N$ is smaller than that yields a likelyhood of zero (since one sample is impossible then), and assuming that $N$ is larger yields a smaller likelyhood, since all the samples are less likely then (here the uniformity of the distribution comes into play).

Comment: @fgp yes, nice idea...! indeed, I will work with that